# How can I write a shell script program to go through all my esql files and then execute that file to create exe files

Tags: bash, shell, embedded-sql

This is what I mean:

```
ls -l *.ec
```

For each result found, I would like to compile it one at a time.

e.g., for $something.ec:

```
esql $something.ec -o $something
```

`$something.ec` is original file

`$something` is target exe file.

My question is: how can I put that into a loop to go through all the files in my directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop as follows:

```
for file in *.ec
do
    esql "$file" -o "${file//.ec}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you write a simple Makefile:

```
INPUTS = $(wildcard *.ec)
all: $(INPUTS:.ec=)

%: %.ec
    esql $@ -o $<
```

and then simply run `make` (or `make -B` to force execution) whenever you want to re-execute them.